# Laravel - Mysql query accented characters

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel

i have a search bar with italians cities, my query list have accents in the name's cities, so my autosuggest ajax call show something like this:

[image]

To show my cities i'm calling query list with ajax, now i would like fix this issue and show the name of cities normaly with accents "à","è"..etc.

I tried to change the option of MySql to `"utf8mb4_general_ci"` or `"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"` to others, without results. Actually i have:

**PhpMyAdmin codify:** `"utf8mb4_general_ci"`

**records:** `"utf8_unicode_ci"`

**VIEW HTML**

```
<html xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" lang="it">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="it" />
```

I don't know how can i show the query of name's cities with accents, thank you for your help! I hope fix this error.

**NB:** maybe i have some idea but i don't know if it possible:

**With my JS**
if there is some way to transform `"value.name"` with accents?, i'm using a loop like this:

```
$.each(response, function(key, value){
    $('#locality').append($('<option>', {
        value: value.id,
        text: value.name,
    }));
});
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: as db and php collations look fine (utf8), can it be a browser issue (wrong codepage set on client-side)? Looks like the typical "Unicode shown as Latin1" problem.

Comment: I updated my question with html reference language and charset

Comment: is the accented character, as you type it into the search box, also shown as Ä²? looks like it on the screenshot... when you set a breakpoint  the browser's JavaScript debugger inside the $.each body, and start typing the accented character, what is the runtime value of `value.name`?

Comment: You should double check the HTTP header (encoding) of your ajax request